# ES6 not compiling

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, react-hot-loader

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here in my webpack.config.js file? The browser gives me an error saying "unexpected token 'import' " which means it is not recognizing ES6 syntax. Am I doing something wrong with the loaders? I've installed and reinstalled dependencies multiple times, so I don't think that's where the issue lies.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './public/index.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      App: 'public/components/App.jsx',
      Home: 'public/components/Home.jsx',
      Footer: 'public/components/Footer.jsx',
      Inventory: 'public/components/Inventory.jsx',
      Login: 'public/components/nav/Login.jsx',
      Navbar: 'public/components/nav/Navbar.jsx',
      ProductSearch: 'public/components/Product-Search.jsx',
      SingleProduct: 'public/components/Single-Product.jsx',
      Product: 'public/components/Product.jsx',
      Signup: 'public/components/Signup.jsx',
      LandingNavbar: 'public/components/nav/LandingNavbar.jsx',
      ProductSearch: 'public/components/ProductSearch.jsx',
      Examples: 'public/components/Examples.jsx',
      Pricing: 'public/components/Pricing.jsx',
      Profile: 'public/components/Profile.jsx',
      Checkout: 'public/components/Checkout.jsx',
      Receipt: 'public/components/Receipt.jsx',
      RequireAuth: 'public/components/auth/require_auth.jsx',
      Signout: 'public/components/Signout.jsx',
      Tour: 'public/components/tour/Tour.jsx',
      BusinessTypes: 'public/components/tour/BusinessTypes.jsx',
      Customers: 'public/components/tour/Customers.jsx',
      Features: 'public/components/tour/Features.jsx',
      GettingStarted: 'public/components/tour/GettingStarted.jsx',
      MultiStore: 'public/components/tour/MultiStore.jsx',
      Support: 'public/components/tour/Support.jsx',
      Actions: 'public/actions/index.js'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot','babel-loader', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'], 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you installed `babel-preset-es2015`?

Answer (score 0):

What file gives you this error? `public/actions/index.js`? You are not passing your `.js` files to babel.
And you are calling babel-loader twice. First as "babel-loader" without any preset and second as "babel" with presets.

Correct loaders would be:

```
loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react'], 
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }]
```

Note changed test regexp. Now it covers .js and .jsx files. And I suggest moving presets into .babelrc file

Comment: public/reducers/index.js is the file throwing the error, so what should I do to the loaders to correct this?

Comment: Thank you. If I added a babelrc file, where would I reference it here? Or would I need to reference it at all?

Comment: Just put it next to webpack.config.js in "project root". You don't have to mention it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have the babel loader twice. Just remove 'babel-loader' from your array of loaders. This is because "babel?..." is calling the loader already.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json must have babel-loader in it. So make sure you run:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Then this in your webpack config file:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
      },
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }]
  }
```

If that works, then try adding 'react-hot' to your list of loaders.